# XMPP user presence itself

Tags: android, xmpp, user-presence

In my application there is a requirement. I want to get the presence and mode of the login user itself how can i get that???

```
 Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
    Presence checkPresence = roster.getPresence(useritself);
```

When I use this code to get the presence of the login user it always gives me unavailable.

How can I get the presence of login user itself by this means or any other means

Answer (score 2):

Is `useritself` a bare (localpart@domainpart) JID?  Is `useritself` logged in on a different device?  If not, depending on the server, you may not receive presence from yourself.  Also, make sure that you're not doing this presence check until after you've *received* all of the presence.  The best way to achieve this is to register a callback for presence changes, rather than querying for the current presence state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I am maintaining a scenario for which I receive notification when I am not on a particular screen. Now If a am on that particular screen I should not receive notications. For that purpose I want to check presence if i am on that screen or not?